# Certbot fails on Ubuntu 18.04 Apache 2.4.29

Tags: apache, certbot, nextcloud

I´m trying to set up SSL for my nextcloud server via Let´s Encrypt. But I get the error

```
Failed authorization procedure. my.ddnsurl.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization
```

using the `certbot --apache` command. Any ideas to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Count Omega